# How does R2-D2 hack into everything?

Tags: star-wars, computers

How is it that astromech droids like R2-D2 and Chopper can hack into computer systems so easily? They must be doing something very advanced. I know in 1977; cybersecurity was very new (non-existent) but if you look at it from an in-universe point of view; I’m sure Star Wars computer tech has network segmentation and Two-factor authentication. What could they possibly be doing?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You say "I’m sure Star Wars computer tech has network segmentation and Two-factor authentication."  How are you sure?  Spaceships fly in ether; why would electronics behave exactly like ours?

Comment: Ether? No. They fly in a vacuum; they use repulsorlifts in atmosphere, ion engines to get out of the gravity well and then hyperdrive.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/252482/101407

Comment: Artoo probably bought a list of old Imperial passwords off a disgruntled employee.

Comment: That’s interesting but Pablo Hidalgo has no clue what he is talking about. The Story Group is incredibly lazy and doesn’t give a crap about their jobs. 

The Lords of the Sith (canon novel) referenced that there was no sound in space. The sound is just for the benefit of the audience. Banking is due to repulsorlifts. Etc

Comment: @Aaron - Then why do ships in Star Wars have a maximum speed *in space*?