# Is there anything to the idea of an "Uncle Ben" trope?

Tags: star-wars, marvel, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, spider-man, trope

There seems to be a trend of Uncles Ben who inspire a protagonist and then die (or at least appear to), inspiring them some more:

- Spider-Man's Uncle Ben
- Luke Skywalker's "uncle" Ben Kenobi (uncle in role even if not labeled such)
- Jon Snow's Uncle Benjen (who may or may not be alive)

Are there more Uncles Ben we can add to this list?

And is there any evidence that any of the Bens were named by their writers in homage to earlier examples?

I suspect the Star Wars case is coincidental, but G.R.R. Martin could have done it on purpose; it would not be out of character for him.

---

There is a [John Carter character](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123702/who-is-ben-in-the-john-carter-universe/123709#123709) called "uncle Ben" or "old Ben" which would precede all of the above cases. He, however, does not seem to inspire or tragically die, that we know of.

Comment: Spam! Advertising [Uncle Ben's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Ben's)! Just kidding ;-)

Comment: I sense a plot to endorse the Uncle Ben rice order. ;)

Comment: @randal'thor Did someone die to inspire that? :p

Comment: we don't even know what has happened to Benjen yet, so this is highly speculative if you are looking at it from a *GOT/ASOIAF* perspective.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister not really, that they stay dead is not important. It's the inspiration they give to our protagonist in the meantime that matters. I'm looking for more examples or a comment by GRRM, not speculation. And I don't want to ruin anything for you about spider-man's uncle Ben, but....

Comment: @JoshuaBigbee your words "who inspire a protagonist and then die". You might want to reword that because as I said *we don't know what happened to him yet*.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister my response is... From a certain point if view....

Comment: Well whose to say Peter's uncle Ben will *stay* dead? Bucky and Jason are alive ...

Comment: [Obi-Wan was never referred to as uncle Ben](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/132766/769) (and Luke's uncle was named Owen) and given [they barely spent time together](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/108495/769) Luke probably wouldn't have considered him "uncle" even in quotation marks. Plus, Obi-Wan was not exactly dead...

Comment: @Joshua Uncle Ben's rice inspired generations of commercial chefs, then Uncle Ben died from all of the carbs, inspiring them even more to make money off low carb products

Comment: I’m not sure three examples in 35 years constitutes a trend; and as others have observed, I think you mean [Uncles](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/ultra/images/5/56/Spider-Man-2002-Uncle-Ben-Cliff-Robertson-great-power.png/revision/latest?cb=20151113030943) [Ben](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/8c/25/09/8c2509c5ecf0997ebaad813b1f2530d1.jpg), not [Uncle Ben’s](http://www.benekeith.com/images/food/UNCLE-BENS-HEAD-WITH-LOGO-BANNER-SIZE.jpg).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite My question is asking if there are more I don't know of and you're criticizing me for only having 3 in 35 years? I haven't read every book and seen every movie. They were 3 examples I knew of. The point of the question was to find more and establish if there is a trend. Clearly now it seems there is none, but we wouldn't know until we asked, would we?

Comment: @Joshua: I didn’t intend to criticise you, although I do think I was a bit generous when I said “three” — Ben Kenobi isn’t an Uncle, and Uncle Benjen isn’t a Ben! I like the idea though.

Comment: And a reverse: Ben 10 and his grandfather (not uncle) Max.

Answer (score -2):

Considering that [Ben](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben) is the short for Benjamin, Bennett, Benedict... which are common names in english speaking countries, I would say is a coincidence.

*Source : https://www.ssa.gov/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi*

You could probably do the same with another name and find some similitudes if you want.