# Who is Ben in the John Carter universe?

Tags: character-identification, john-carter

I have found references to a character named Ben (old Ben or Uncle Ben) in a John Carter book. However, all I can find about him is he was likely a slave (or, "bondservant").

**Is there any more information on this character? His importance, connection to John Carter, and what happens to him?** Spoilers allowed.

---

I came across this is character while researching this question:

[Is there anything to the idea of an "Uncle Ben" trope?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/123114/62394)

While it does not seem to be what I was looking for, it has raised some other questions,  which I think may be obvious, but I will refrain from giving free advertising (until I get my check).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character of Ben appears very briefly in 'The Gods of Mars'

> Thus was I lost in useless speculation one sultry August evening when
>   old Ben, my body servant, handed me a telegram. Tearing it open I
>   read: 'Meet me to-morrow hotel Raleigh Richmond.

The character is also described in the character glossary at the rear of the book

> *Old Ben (or Uncle Ben).:The writer's body-servant (coloured)*

The note that this individual was referred to as "uncle" would strongly suggest that this character was a black slave being used as a personal valet. This would be in keeping with the general setting of the book and the time period (e.g. the late 19th Century). His fate seems to be unknown.

Comment: Apparently he makes a mean julep too.

Comment: @JoshuaBigbee - History doesn't record the fate of the julep

Comment: There's another quote where the one guy tells the other he must have had too many of old Ben's (mint) juleps. Sorry, forgot about this question :)

Comment: Ah, so the mystery julep probably was consumed eagerly. At least that clears up one mystery.