# Did Luke Skywalker ever refer to Obi-Wan as "Uncle Ben?"

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, names, luke-skywalker, obi-wan-kenobi

Until recently, the Wikipedia article for Peter Parker's [Uncle Ben](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uncle_Ben&oldid=726386636) said this at the top:

[image: For the Star Wars character that Luke Skywalker called Uncle Ben, see Obi-Wan Kenobi]

As far as I can remember, Luke never refers to Obi-Wan as "Uncle Ben" in any of the films, or any of the EU works I've encountered, merely "Ben" or "Old Ben."

Has Luke Skywalker ever referred to Obi-Wan Kenobi as "Uncle Ben" in any official *Star Wars* work?

Comment: Perhaps in a translation. Or, maybe it's about the rice.

Comment: Think he called him "Old Ben" at one point. Might have been thinking of that.

Comment: Someone mixed that up with the Uncle Ben's commercial :)

Comment: Note that at the time of this comment, the link to the Obi-Wan Kenobi page no longer appears at the top of the Wikipedia page for Peter Parker's Uncle Ben.

Comment: I think, originally, undercover Yoda feeds them instant rice with the gruel, but that got pulled when the endorsement deal fell through.

Yes, I am kidding.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Sorted.

Comment: Could ask [Davidwr](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uncle_Ben&diff=696263832&oldid=688792867).

Comment: @amaranth I have [notified](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=User_talk:Davidwr&diff=726952844&oldid=726267084) Davidwr. (I located the change myself and only saw your comment when I went to add this one.)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The nice thing about e-Books: searches. The phrase "Uncle Ben" does not appear in the *Star Wars* novelization. There are 55 instances of "uncle" and all of them refer to Uncle Owen.

Thanks to Valorum, we know the phrase "Uncle Ben" doesn't appear in any of the 17 official novelisations, nor in any of the new "Journey to the Force Awakens" novels, nor anywhere in the 256 books that make up the EU. And that the word "Uncle" that appears over 50 times (in all 17 novelisations) usually to refers to Owen. It appears more than 1800 times in the EU novels (Mostly to refer to Uncle Luke, Uncle Owen or Uncle Hoole)

Comment: You still almost made me pull out the SW movies and pull an all-nighter with this answer..

Comment: You may want to note that the phrase "Uncle Ben" doesn't appear in any of the 17 official novelisations, nor in any of the new "Journey to the  Force Awakens" novels, nor anywhere in the 256 books that make up the EU.

Comment: Re: The word "Uncle", that word appears over 50 times (in all 17 novelisations) usually to refer to Owen. It appears more than 1800 times in the EU novels (Mostly to refer to Uncle Luke, Uncle Owen or Uncle Hoole).

Comment: @phyrfox- The sacrifices we make for the truth.

Comment: Also helpful https://youtu.be/5GFW-eEWXlc?t=38m12s

Comment: @phyrfox This is why I love and hate sci-fi fans. Depending on which side of an argument I'm on.

Comment: Going along with @mikeTheLiar, there's also 11 instances of the word 'Ben' in ANH.  https://youtu.be/5GFW-eEWXlc?t=245

Answer (score 25):

In the third draft of the script for *Return of the Jedi*, [Obi-Wan Kenobi and Owen Lars were revealed to be brothers.](https://books.google.com/books?id=CibfKMB7Gn0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=star%20wars%20the%20essential%20reader%27s%20companion&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5jonB8cDNAhWB5CYKHZ1ZCucQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=brother&f=false)  This would have made Obi-Wan Luke's uncle (since it had already been established that his father was Vader), but it was cut from the movie.  This idea found its way into the book *Jedi Apprentice:  The Hidden Past*.  More importantly, [it also appears in the novelization of *Return of the Jedi*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CibfKMB7Gn0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=star%20wars%20the%20essential%20reader%27s%20companion&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5jonB8cDNAhWB5CYKHZ1ZCucQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=brother&f=false).  Thus, it doesn't matter whether Luke said it or not - Obi-Wan *was* Luke's uncle...  from a certain point of view.

It is possible that this fact has been misinterpreted as Luke actually calling Obi-Wan his uncle.  It isn't entirely out of the question that Luke actually *did* call him "Uncle Ben" in some sources.

> **Ben continued his narrative** . “When your father left, he didn’t know your mother was pregnant. Your mother and I knew he would find out eventually, but we wanted to keep you both as safe as possible, for as long as possible. **So I took you to live with *my brother Owen*, on Tatooine...** and your mother took Leia to live as the daughter of Senator Organa, on Alderaan.”
>   -  *Return of the Jedi: Star Wars: Episode VI* (p. 66).

There you have it:  **"Ben"** reveals himself to be **Luke's uncle**.

Comment: " from a certain point of view." +1. Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112540/how-many-times-was-obi-wan-less-than-honest-with-luke

Comment: Although, even in this account, it's not a blood relation.  "Uncle" Owen is actually the son of Anakin's step-father by a woman other than his mother. Uncles frequently aren't blood relatives because we don't distinguish them from uncles-in-law, although in this case it's more like step-uncle.

Comment: @Michael - I choose to ignore the PT, so for me, if Obi-Wan was Owen's brother, he'd be Luke's uncle.

Comment: I don't think anywhere in [M-canon](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9589/what-should-happen-with-this-list-based-question/9590?noredirect=1#comment26154_9590) it is established that either of the Larses are actually related to either of Luke's parents. So this answer could benefit from the addition of where we learn that the Larses are actually Luke's biological Aunt and Uncle instead of just a kindly couple that took him in whom he *calls* Aunt and Uncle. Because if it's the latter, then Owen and Ben being brothers still wouldn't make Ben Luke's uncle.

Comment: Soooo, begs the question: Why the name Obi-Wan "Ben" Kenobi as opposed to, say, Ben Lars? Is it like the Anakin Skywalker -> Darth Vader thing where some people get a Jedi name upon initiation?

Comment: Anakin and Owen are step brothers through Shmi and Cliegg's marriage, so Owen is Luke's true uncle (just not in blood). If Obi-Wan and Owen are (blood? step? half?) brothers by this reveil, then Anakin and Obi-Wan are also (step? in-law?) brothers, and Obi-Wan would have had to realize that during Anakin's apprenticeship (knowing Anakin's parentage) before they fought in ROTS. Messed up!

Answer (score 4):

I believe, that in the German translation, Luke refers to him as “Onkel Ben“, which is the German word for uncle.
Unfortunately I don't have any sources at the moment, but i will look for some when i get home.

So if someone watched the German version and happened to edit the article, it would explain this.

Comment: For a second "Onkel Ben" also rung a bell to me - but when I watched Star Wars for the first time, I was young and probably simply didn't hear the difference between "Owen" (a name you usually didn't hear in German) and "Ben". Maybe the author of that claim also misheard it....

Comment: if thats true, thats another reason, why in germany you you should STOP  translating the voices on every damn series and movies....

Comment: I watched the german movies many times and I don't recall such a thing.

Comment: Its's been some time since i've last seen the movies. So i guess i must've confused it with something else. Sorry

Comment: @hedgehog: What's the difference between dubbed voices erroneously saying *Onkel Ben* and subtitles erroneously saying *Onkel Ben*?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper that if you always listen to German you will NEVER learn English, wether if you just have the subtitles to help you understand some parts you didnt, then you hear English and you actually learn & even better get to see the movie in the original form, because however you want to put it, if you translate a movie or series its not gonna be the same, for example... Its TOTALLY different if you see Bing Bang Theory with german voices and the original one, i mean half of the fun is on sheldons voice....!!! get it now?

Comment: @hedgehog: When there are subtitles, I cannot make myself listen because reading the subtitles is just so much faster. That's why I prefer watching the original version without subtitles if I understand the original language. Still, my experience is that when people who are not fluent in a language watch a film with subtitles, the film's audio track is completely ignored (e.g. drowned in chatter), thus probably negating any learning effect. In any case, voices sound oddly "wrong" because the distinctive voices from the dubbed version are missing when you were used to the dubbed version.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper that is correct, and even the slightly possibility of them learning something or familiarizing with a language is completely gone....

Answer (score -1):

He does refer to him as "Old Ben", but never as "Uncle Ben". You can verify this by searching for "Uncle Ben" in the film's script, available at:

http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html

Comment: Try to avoid link only answers. Take the relevant text and source it your answer. This helps if a link ever goes dead.

Comment: @Skooba what part of the movie's script would be relevant to prove that a particular sentence is never uttered? I know why link only answers are bad, but nios can hardly copy the entire script into their answer!

Comment: @terdon it came up on the First Posts review... just trying offer advice for this and future posts. I see your point in context now, but considering how short the answer is, it still needs a bit more effort to turn it into a good answer.

Comment: @Skooba no argument there. I did what I could, for what it's worth.

Comment: Citing doesn't make sense, but one worthwhile expansion of this answer would be to verify that every place in the script the word "uncle" is used, it doesn't refer to Obi-Wan. The absence of the phrase "uncle Ben" is very important, and directly relates to the question, but if it's possible that at some point Obi-Wan is referred to as "uncle", then that would be good to know or disprove. Also, it would help to look at all the scripts for at least episodes V - VII.

Comment: Actually I answered based on my memory of the movies, nothing else. I will be careful when linking a source in the future !

Answer (score -2):

**NO!**

There is no reference in any book, in any script, in any novelisation of Luke Skywalker ever reffering to Obi-Wan as "Uncle Ben".

You always have to remember that *Wikipedia* is an **open free library** anyone can alter the information whether its correct or not. **Dont always count** on the information you find there.

Propably someone with `no knowledge` of Star-Wars added that information there, because as others can verify as well the only "uncle" that exists in the SW Universe is "Uncle Owen".

I just fixed the referenced *Wikipedia's* article by the way.

Comment: Maybe someone was trying [Citogenesis](https://xkcd.com/978/)

Comment: @Zommuter nahhhh more like someone mistaken the "Uncle Owen" & "Old Ben-Kenobi" names....

Comment: The question was not about if Wikipedia *was correct*, it asking about the SW canon.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to answer the question asked, other that peripherally focusing on the question of why wikipedia might be wrong.

Comment: @Valorum from when saying NO to something isnt an answer? the rest is the explanation why the reference of the question is wrong....

Comment: @hedgehog - As I said. Your answer does answer the main question but seems to treat it as an afterthought to dealing with the wikipedia article. You've also failed to supply any evidence to back up your contention

Comment: Considering Wad's answer, it also looks like this answer is simply wrong, with the only thing being somewhat right is the Wikipedia rant.